# Swift Closure semaphore wait for Facebook graph query

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, grand-central-dispatch

I'm performing a Facebook graph query to extract information from the user profile. The call is triggered by the Facebook login button (UIView) so I need to wait for it to be completed before I progress. I added some logging and it seems to me that the graph request is asynchronous? I want to call it synchronously as I'm using it to populate my internal `User` object.

```
var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
request.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            //handle error
        } else {
            //extract info from result
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    })
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

In an attempt to wait for the Facebook call to complete I have added a semaphore wait using GCD but now I never hit a breakpoint inside the handler. I just wait forever; it seems I have created a deadlock.

What is the correct way to run an async closure synchronously? I could just set a flag and setup an empty loop but I'd rather avoid such hacks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you are taking the right approach. Rather than make the asynchronous task synchronous, you should have your UI wait for the response. The most widespread way of doing that is by using a HUD to let the user know that the app is doing something thus explaining the unresponsive UI.

You have many HUD libraries that you can use out of the box or you can design your own. This is an example using the popular SVProgressHUD in Obj-c but it's the same story in swift:

```
[SVProgressHUD show]; // This will block the UI
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Your async task here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //your async task is finished
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; // this will free up the UI
    });
});
```

https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD

Comment: take a look at the link i put in the answer. It's a little animation that tells the user something is going on and they need to wait.